# Is there any Web API for Google web clipboard?

Tags: web, clipboard, copy-paste, google-docs, google-docs-api

Google Docs have a feature "Web Clipboard" to help users easily copy and paste cross google documents. (you can refer to https://drive.googleblog.com/2010/02/a-web-clipboard-for-google-docs.html)

But I am wondering that if there's any Web API or official way to access those API.
I try to find in Google Document List APi (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/), I can't find any related stuff.

The original goal for me is I want to copy some screenshot/images/text from my Windows OS.
And I want to paste into my GoogleDoc Document.
But it can't be done unless the screenshot/image/text is update/upload into Web Clipboard.

I keep finding any related integrated tools or extension, but I still can't find anyone.
Could someone give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official way to access this API, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There is clearly an API of sorts, just not documented. I'd suggest looking at extensions [like this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/giiigfhfnbpiclcphiopambeanhenafa?hl=en-US) and trying to reverse-engineer the protocol so you can see what endpoints it is calling.

But it sounds like a lot of work.