# Clipboard manipulation on Google Apps?

Tags: google-apps-script, clipboard, google-apps

Is there anyway to access and manipulate clipboard on a Google Docs document?

I checked in Google App Script docs and blogs and couldn't find a way for this yet..

The idea is to wrap a fixed text string around copied text, so copying:

```
AAAAAA
```

would let the user paste:

```
" AAAAAAA " (appended_text_string)
```

So users could copy text quotes out of a given document, and paste the text in Powerpoint with quotation marks and some additional text data appended around it.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57681314/add-content-of-showmodaldialog-to-the-clipboard-google-script

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no way to do this. Google Drive offers a web clipboard, but it not accessible through the API.

See [Is there any Web API for Google web clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202863/is-there-any-web-api-for-google-web-clipboard)